# Pass variable as parameter to a .sh file

Tags: bash

Below is my script where i need to pass the password as parameter

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set password [lindex $argv 0];
spawn iroot
expect ".* password for"
sleep 3
send "$password\r"
sleep 5
send "dmidecode -t system | grep Manufacturer > /tmp/manufacdetails.txt\r"
send "exit\r"
interact
```

i tried executing this like below

```
./getmanufacdetailsTest.sh password123
```

But it doesn't seems to be working. can you please tell me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: use `-d` flag to find out where your script is getting stuck.

Comment: See Vlad's answer or consider to use the [highly popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14203146/4039619) that explains how to do it in multiple ways,

Answer (score 2):

prog.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
echo "the arg passed to my prog is $1"
```

In console:
`./prog.sh one1`
Outputs: `one1`